# Parking space availability using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm trying to determine parking space availability/occupancy given an input image. Ideally I'd like to indicate open spots with some marking or atleast output the number of empty spots. 
I'm very new to OpenCV and I'm lost on what approach to take.
So far I have tried

1. Canny Edge Detection and Hough Line Transforms -  in the hope to detect lines, but the output was not really good. See the result below:
   [image: Canny Output]
2. Background Subtraction - output shows me double edges when I fed 3 different images because the orientation is not the same always, so I figured this doesn't really work.
3. Now, I'm trying SimpleBlobDetector to detect cars but having difficulty in getting it to work with any car.

   Please suggest what approach works best.

Comment: Are we doing this for just this parking lot, or for any parking lot? You say the same orientation isn't guaranteed - is there anything guaranteed about the camera? (x,y,z position, roll, pitch, or yaw angle, same camera [with same zoom level / focus], etc)

Comment: Its just for this lot. The camera itself and everything is going to be the same except for orientation - it can be slightly off.

Comment: If it is just for this parking lot, can you build a map of the lot, and then align the current image to the map through rotation or skew?